# Sync phone Contacts with Database Android application

Tags: android, synchronization, android-contacts, contacts, contact-form

and Iam currently working on an android application which syncs the users contact 
and shows those people as user's friends who are in there contact by searching in the database.
This uses a very similar technique as whatsapp.
Iam new to this .And if anyone could help me it would be very kind.Please tell me where should I start from.Also please give me some refference for this.
any help woold be appriciable.Please do help.
Thaks in advance :-))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)

Ultimately you have to use

```
new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                contentUri,
                ContactMobileNumbQuery.PROJECTION,
                ContactMobileNumbQuery.SELECTION,
                null,
                ContactMobileNumbQuery.SORT_ORDER);
```

The above code retrives all phone numbers with name using the below interface in your cursor

```
/**
 * This interface defines constants used by mobile number retrieval queries.
 */
public interface ContactMobileNumbQuery{
    final static int QUERY_ID = 1;

    //A Content Uri for Phone table
    final static Uri CONTENT_URI = Phone.CONTENT_URI;   

    //The search or filter query Uri
    final static Uri FILTER_URI = Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI;

    // The selection clause for the CursorLoader query. The search criteria defined here
    // restrict results to contacts that have a phone number and display name.
    // Notice that the search on the string provided by the user is implemented by appending
    // the search string to CONTENT_FILTER_URI.
    final static String SELECTION = Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1" + " AND " + Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + "<>''";

    // The desired sort order for the returned Cursor - Order by DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY 
    //in Ascending with case insensitively
    final static String SORT_ORDER = Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

    // The projection for the CursorLoader query. This is a list of columns that the Contacts
    // Provider should return in the Cursor.
    final static String[] PROJECTION = {

        // The contact's row id
        Phone._ID,

        // the Contacts table contains DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, which either contains 
        // the contact's displayable name or some other useful identifier such as an 
        // email address.
        Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,

        // A pointer to the contact that is guaranteed to be more permanent than _ID. Given
        // a contact's current _ID value and LOOKUP_KEY, the Contacts Provider can generate
        // a "permanent" contact URI.
        Phone.LOOKUP_KEY,

        //Phone number of the contact
        Phone.NUMBER,
    };
    // The query column numbers which map to each value in the projection
    final static int ID = 0;
    final static int DISPLAY_NAME = 1;
    final static int LOOKUP_KEY = 2;
    final static int NUMBER = 3;
}
```

The sync logic has to written seperately. Try it and post your comments :)

Comment: Mark it as correct Answer if it really fixes ur problem :-)